# AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF in Word Addin (32bit & 64bit)

Tags: .net, pdf, ms-word, activex, axacropdf

i'm trying to get the active x control (adobe acrobat - AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF) to work within my word 2010 addin.
when i'm building the addin with target platform x32 it works. the problem is that i need this also as a x64 addin, because otherwise it won't work with 64bit-word.

with target platform (any or x64):
Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

is there any possibilty to get the AxAcroPDF (32bit) to work in a application which is build with target platform (any or x64)?

Comment: Its not possible to use a 32-bit active X control within a 64-bit process. Your only choice is to use the 64-bit dll if it eixsts.  Of course I would just use the 32-bit version of Word if the add-on is that important.  I have no idea if the 64-bit of Word even supports add-ons my guess it does but only 64-bit dlls.

Answer (score 1):

You're stuck with the 32 bit/x86 control, so your addin needs to be 32 bit/x86 to use the control, and thus Word needs to be 32 bit/x86 as well to load the addin, as Microsoft [recommend here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681792.aspx):

> If users in your organization depend on existing extensions to Office,
>   such as **ActiveX controls**, third-party add-ins, in-house solutions
>   built on previous versions of Office, or 32-bit versions of programs
>   that interface directly with Office, **we recommend that you install
>   32-bit (x86) Office 2010** (the default installation) on computers that
>   are running both 32-bit and 64-bit supported Windows operating
>   systems.